# Determining if two time series are cointegrated

Tags: time-series, normal-distribution, cointegration

I'm currently working on a problem where I am given that

- $\epsilon_t$ is a series of independent draws from a N(0,1) distribution
- $w_t$ is another series of independent draws from a N(0,1) distribution. Each $w_t$ is distributed independently of all $\epsilon_t$s
- $x_t = \sum_{s=1}^t \epsilon_s$
- $z_t = x_t + w_t$

and am asked whether $x_t$ and $z_t$ are cointegrated.

First I've determined that $s_t$ and $z_t$ are I(1)/Have order of integration 1 since for $x_t$:

$$
x_t = \sum_{s=1}^t \epsilon_s = \sum_{s=1}^{t-1} \epsilon_s + \epsilon_t = x_{t-1} +\epsilon_t
$$

which through some rearrangement yields:

$$
x_t - x_{t-1} = \epsilon_t
$$

where $\epsilon_t$ is a stationary process since it has a constant mean, variance, and an autocovariance that is not dependent on time. For $z_t$

$$
z_t = x_t + w_t = x_{t-1} + \epsilon_t + w_t
$$

$$
z_{t-1} = x_{t-1} + w_{t-1}
$$

so

$$
z_t - z_{t-1} = x_{t-1} + \epsilon_t + w_t - (x_{t-1} + w_{t-1}) = \epsilon_t + w_t - w_{t-1}
$$

where $\epsilon_t + w_t - w_{t-1}$ is stationary since it is a linear combination of normal distributions N(0,1). However, I'm not 100% confident in this.

Moreover, I'm not sure about how to go about determining the cointegration from here. I know for non-stationary and cointegrated series $a_t$ and $b_t$, there must exist a $\beta$ such that

$$
a_t - \beta b_t = u_t
$$

where $u_t$ is a stationary process. From this, I could do:

$$
z_t - \beta x_t = x_t + w_t - \beta x_t
$$

and setting $\beta = 1$ would then give

$$
z_t - \beta x_t = x_t + w_t - 1 x_t = w_t = u_t
$$

where $w_t$ would be a stationary process and therefore fulfill the necessary requirement.

But are $x_t$ and $z_t$ non-stationary if they are pretty much just linear combinations of normal distributions N(0,1)? And is my assumption about the stationarity of the normal distribution right?

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: Hint: consider $z_t - 1x_t$.

Comment: I apologize @TheLaconic , I realize that zt−1xt would suffice as long as zt and xt meet the requirements of being non-stationary. My issue is more about whether or not zt and xt are non-stationary given that they are linear combinations of the normal distribution N(0,1), which I take as stationary.

Comment: Being a "linear combination of the normal distribution" isn't a sufficient condition for stationarity.  Each *individual* $x_t$ is a sum of normally-distributed variables, but each individual $x_t$ is not a series.  You can't talk about the mean or variance changing (or not) over time if there's only one time.  Stationarity (or not) is a feature of the series of $x_t$.

Comment: Then can I even say that $z_t$ is I(1) when $z_t - z_{t-1} = \epsilon_t + w_t - w_{t-1}$ ?

Comment: Hint: compute the mean and variance of $x_t$ for some $t$, and then see whether one of those depends on $t$.  If either depends on $t$, it's not stationary, whichever definition of "stationary" you're using (and whatever version of stationary you *are* using, that should be guiding your approach).